# How do you install knative serving on my own local k8s cluster?

Tags: knative-serving

I'm trying to install [Knative Serving](https://github.com/knative/serving) on my own local k8s cluster. All the instructions are specific to cloud providers though, are there instructions for installing on a generic k8s cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a pull request, which answers this question: https://github.com/knative/docs/pull/251

The instructions are basically the same as installing on another cluster:

1. Install Istio:

   `kubectl apply -f https://storage.googleapis.com/knative-releases/serving/latest/istio.yaml`
2. Label the default namespace with `istio-injection=enabled`:

   `kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled`

Then install Knative:

```
kubectl apply -f https://storage.googleapis.com/knative- 
releases/serving/latest/release.yaml
```